# getJson returns all Handlers instead of data

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson

i am trying to load a config.json from my filesystem in an html application:

```
var data = $.getJSON('../../modules/config.json');
console.log(data);
```

but i don´t receive the data from the json file (the path is correct, i checked it twice) instead i got this:

```
Object {readyState: 1, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}abort: function (a){var b=a||u;return i&&i.abort(b),x(0,b),this}always: function (){return e.done(arguments).fail(arguments),this}complete: function (){if(h){var d=h.length;!function f(b){m.each(b,function(b,c){var d=m.type(c);"function"===d?a.unique&&k.has(c)||h.push(c):c&&c.length&&"string"!==d&&f(c)})}(arguments),b?e=h.length:c&&(g=d,j(c))}return this}done: function (){if(h){var d=h.length;!function f(b){m.each(b,function(b,c){var d=m.type(c);"function"===d?a.unique&&k.has(c)||h.push(c):c&&c.length&&"string"!==d&&f(c)})}(arguments),b?e=h.length:c&&(g=d,j(c))}return this}arguments: nullcaller: nulllength: 0name: ""prototype: m.Callbacks.k.add__proto__: function Empty() {}<function scope>error: function (){if(h){var d=h.length;!function f(b){m.each(b,function(b,c){var d=m.type(c);"function"===d?a.unique&&k.has(c)||h.push(c):c&&c.length&&"string"!==d&&f(c)})}(arguments),b?e=h.length:c&&(g=d,j(c))}return this}fail: function (){if(h){var d=h.length;!function f(b){m.each(b,function(b,c){var d=m.type(c);"function"===d?a.unique&&k.has(c)||h.push(c):c&&c.length&&"string"!==d&&f(c)})}(arguments),b?e=h.length:c&&(g=d,j(c))}return this}getAllResponseHeaders: function (){return 2===t?f:null}getResponseHeader: function (a){var b;if(2===t){if(!j){j={};while(b=Cc.exec(f))j[b[1].toLowerCase()]=b[2]}b=j[a.toLowerCase()]}return null==b?null:b}overrideMimeType: function (a){return t||(k.mimeType=a),this}pipe: function (){var a=arguments;return m.Deferred(function(c){m.each(b,function(b,f){var g=m.isFunction(a[b])&&a[b];e[f[1]](function(){var a=g&&g.apply(this,arguments);a&&m.isFunction(a.promise)?a.promise().done(c.resolve).fail(c.reject).progress(c.notify):c[f[0]+"With"](this===d?c.promise():this,g?[a]:arguments)})}),a=null}).promise()}progress: function (){if(h){var d=h.length;!function f(b){m.each(b,function(b,c){var d=m.type(c);"function"===d?a.unique&&k.has(c)||h.push(c):c&&c.length&&"string"!==d&&f(c)})}(arguments),b?e=h.length:c&&(g=d,j(c))}return this}promise: function (a){return null!=a?m.extend(a,d):d}readyState: 1setRequestHeader: function (a,b){var c=a.toLowerCase();return t||(a=s[c]=s[c]||a,r[a]=b),this}state: function (){return c}statusCode: function (a){var b;if(a)if(2>t)for(b in a)q[b]=[q[b],a[b]];else v.always(a[v.status]);return this}success: function (){if(h){var d=h.length;!function f(b){m.each(b,function(b,c){var d=m.type(c);"function"===d?a.unique&&k.has(c)||h.push(c):c&&c.length&&"string"!==d&&f(c)})}(arguments),b?e=h.length:c&&(g=d,j(c))}return this}arguments: nullcaller: nulllength: 0name: ""prototype: m.Callbacks.k.add__proto__: function Empty() {}<function scope>then: function (){var a=arguments;return m.Deferred(function(c){m.each(b,function(b,f){var g=m.isFunction(a[b])&&a[b];e[f[1]](function(){var a=g&&g.apply(this,arguments);a&&m.isFunction(a.promise)?a.promise().done(c.resolve).fail(c.reject).progress(c.notify):c[f[0]+"With"](this===d?c.promise():this,g?[a]:arguments)})}),a=null}).promise()}__proto__: Object
```

it seems to be all handlers, but i just want to have my data from the json.file. I think i am just missing an very little thing.

Comment: Just check the doc http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/...
`$.getJSON( "test.js", function( json ) {`
  `console.log( "JSON Data: " + json.users[ 3 ].name );
 `});`

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getJson` function returns an XHR (which is what you're seeing in the console) not the data received by the request. To get the data you need to use the callback parameter:

```
$.getJSON('../../modules/config.json', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: (troll mode) how you know that ? you have read the doc ? unbelievable !

Comment: well, yes obviously, sorry. Thanks for the fast an right answer!

Answer (score 0):

Gets the JSON from the URL:

```
$.getJSON('../../modules/config.json').success(function(data){
    // data is an array
});
```

[Example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frippa/e0kopqnz/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Actually you're missing something big. `$.getJSON` is supposed to work asynchronously. And not with local files of your server. When site becomes public and a user loads your page in his browser, the will no longer be any `local files from server`. The method accepts URL, not a local path, so in the end requested json file should be served by a webserver, and a callback which will execute on success

```
var url = 'http://localhost/yourwebapp/config.json';//for testing locally on developer's pc
$.getJSON(url, function(data){
    var config = JSON.parse(data);
});
```

The return value of `getJSON` is actually a `jqXHR` object which allows to control the request in some way, but not the data

Comment: `The method accepts URL, not a local path` While you're correct that a local path is not allowed, the OP is using a relative path which is entirely acceptable, and arguably better for maintenance.